# How do you test functions defined within $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I'm trying to get a simple test going with QUnit but it won't locate functions defined within $(document).ready().

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="qunit-git.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qunit-git.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit Test Suite</h1>
<h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
<div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
<h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
<ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
test('Blah blah', function() {
  ok(mytest(), 'foo bar'
  );
});
```

**code.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mytest = function() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

***--> "Died on test #1: mytest is not defined..."***

Comment: Why do your functions need to be defined in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `mytest` is a local variable. You can't access it from outside the function it is defined in.

Answer (score 9):

As you start testing, you may find that you need to improve the structure of your code.  Defining functions as local variables inside $(document).ready is strange, and makes it so they cannot be accessed anywhere but in the .ready call.  Move that function somewhere else.